# Why is is series a int when Im declaring it as a float?

Tags: c

Given x and the number of terms.
Display the sum of the series [ 1+x+x^2/2!+x^3/3!+....].

I have tried using type float, double.
I have used casting on the integers.
I have tried a bunch of things.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
int termos;
float series, x, fact;//I have tried it with double because of pow 
                 //function


printf("Input x:"); scanf("%f",&x);
printf("\nInput nº termos:"); scanf("%d",&termos);

for(int i=1,series=1;i<termos;i++)
{
      for(int k=1,fact=1;k<=i;k++)
      {
        fact=fact*(float)k;
        //printf("fact=%f ",fact);
    }

 series= series + pow(x,i)/fact;
 printf("%f.....", series);//line 29

  }
    printf("\n\nFinal:%f \n", series);

return 0;
 }
```

c:29:23: warning: format specifies type 'double' but the argument has type 'int'
      [-Wformat]
    printf("%f.....", series);

Comment: You also need to validate the input read with *scanf*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are declaring an integer `series` with

```
for(int i=1,series=1;i<termos;i++)
```

This `int series` has a scope of the elements inside the for loop. Same `for(int k=1,fact=1;k<=i;k++)`

A possible fix for this is to set the value of `series` before the loop

```
series = 1;
for(int i=1;i<termos;i++)
```

You should always compile your code with `-Wall` to catch such errors.

Comment: Thank you for the correction and also the extra suggestion. And thank you ,again.

Comment: It is better to put the assignment to `series` before the loop than to move the declaration of `i` to before the loop, as the latter unnecessarily enlarges the scope of `i`.

Answer (score 5):

This line: `for(int i=1,series=1;i<termos;i++)`, declares a new `int` named `series`, which shadows the original `float series`.

A possible fix would be to move the initialization out of the `for`, like:

```
series = 1;
for(int i=1;i<termos;i++)
```